# VHDL-Implement LFSR

Tags: vhdl, lfsr

I write below Vhdl code & testbench code for implement LFSR on ISE.
I pick up LFSR code from this path on ISE.
Language Templates--VHDL--Synthesis Constructs--Coding Examples---
Counters---LFSR

My problem is in simulink(isim), i always face with 'U' sign for out_lfsr.
Can you Help me,Please?

vhdl code:

```
    library IEEE;
        use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;



entity lfsr is

port(rst,clk,clk_en:in std_logic;
out_lfsr: inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
init_value:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);

end lfsr;

architecture Behavioral of lfsr is


begin

process(clk)
begin
   if ( clk'event and clk ='1') then
      if (rst = '1') then
         out_lfsr <= init_value;
      elsif clk_en='1' then 
         out_lfsr(31 downto 1) <= out_lfsr(30 downto 0) ;
         out_lfsr(0) <= not(out_lfsr(31) XOR out_lfsr(21) XOR out_lfsr(0)); 
      end if;
   end if;
end process; 


end Behavioral;
```

testbench:

```
    LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;



ENTITY tb_lfsr IS
END tb_lfsr;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_lfsr IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT lfsr
    PORT(
         rst : IN  std_logic;
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         clk_en : IN  std_logic;
         out_lfsr : INOUT  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         init_value : IN  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal rst : std_logic := '0';
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal clk_en : std_logic := '1';
   signal init_value : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '1');

    --Outputs
   signal out_lfsr : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):=(others => '0');

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: lfsr PORT MAP (
          rst => rst,
          clk => clk,
          clk_en => clk_en,
          out_lfsr => out_lfsr,
          init_value => init_value
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;



END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset this block in other to make it work. At reset it loads input value to output.

```
reset_p: process begin
    rst <= '1';
    wait for 10 * clk_period;
    rst <= '0';
    wait;
end process;
```

I think it would also be better to not use inout, as it is not always proper for synthesis, but use internal signal, where you store out_lfsr value.

```
entity lfsr is

port(
    rst,clk,clk_en:in std_logic;
    out_lfsr: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    init_value: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);

end lfsr;

architecture Behavioral of lfsr is

signal s_out_lfsr : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin

process(clk)
begin
   if ( clk'event and clk ='1') then
      if (rst = '1') then
         s_out_lfsr <= init_value;
      elsif clk_en='1' then 
         s_out_lfsr(31 downto 1) <= s_out_lfsr(30 downto 0) ;
         s_out_lfsr(0) <= not(s_out_lfsr(31) XOR s_out_lfsr(21) XOR s_out_lfsr(0)); 
      end if;
   end if;
end process; 

out_lfsr <= s_out_lfsr;

end Behavioral;
```

I'm not entirely sure about that, as your code was in Coding Examples.